# How to Include file1 into another file in magento

Tags: file, magento, include

I have 2 files in Catalog folder of my template. I want to include one file into another file I tried simple php "require('html2fpdf.php');" method but it does not works. Please let me know how can I include this file into other file.

Answer (score 0):

In Magento you use getChildHtml  to include blocks.

Magento work with layout and block concept.
So you need to create a block using some xml and block class file.Also you need to make sure your block is in proper layout handle.